# unwind segue returns to wrong caller

Tags: objective-c, unwind-segue

I've looked at this issue throughout posts here, but can't find my error.

I have vc1 that seques to vcDetail when required.

I also have a vc2 that segues to vcDetail when required.

vc1 and vc2 are organized under a tab controller. vcDetail is not.

vc1 to vcDetail segue is established in storyboard and fired on action.

vc2 to vcDetail segue is established in storyboard and fired on action.

vcDetail dismiss button is "wired" to Exit. Using 'selected' method myUnwindAction.

myUnwindAction is implemented in both vc1 and vc2. identically. defined in .h files too. (and when I click on the unwind segue of vcDetail, both vc1 and vc2 light up, in storyboard editor).

problem: my vcDetail never unwinds back to vc2. It seems to only ever unwind to vc1.

scenarios:

-- presented at tab vcLogin.

--tab to vc1, segue to vcDetail. unwind to vc1. ok.

--tab to vc2, segue to vcDetail. unwind to vc1 -- wrong. need to return to caller, vc2.

or:

--presented at tab vcLogin.

--tab to vc1, do not segue.

--tab to vc2, segue to vcDetail. unwind to vc1 -- wrong. need to return to caller, vc2.

I'm stuck. How do I return to proper vc caller? It is as if regardless of source, the unwind was always returning to vc1's "myUnwindAction". As if vc2 did not exist. yet the unwind methods are there, and the storyboard editor seems to know both are participating in myUnwindAction (hence the highlighting mentioned).

Comment: I don't have a complete answer yet; but it appears the culprit is the tab controller. When I remove the VCs from the tab controller, the unwinds behave correctly... I'll keep hunting, because I like my UI to be organized with tabs...

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to create different unwind segue for each Tab's View Controller
 create unwind method in VC2 like 
-(IBAction)unwindFromvcDetailToVC2:(UIStoryboardSegue*)sender;

 create unwind method in VC1 like 
-(IBAction)unwindFromvcDetailToVC1:(UIStoryboardSegue*)sender;

set Both unwindSegue through Storyboard

Depend on ur condition/requirement call
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindFromvcDetailToVC2" sender:nil];

or

 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindFromvcDetailToVC1" sender:nil];
```